# liquibase and orai18n.jar

Tags: java, oracle, jar, liquibase

I can't run this

```
liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --classpath=ojdbc8.jar --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid" --changeLogFile=db.xml --username=name --password=psw generateChangeLog
```

I get an error

> "Unexpected error running Liquibase:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException:
>   Unsupported code table (add orai18n.jar to the class route):
>   CL8MSWIN1251"

Full stack error

> Liquibase Community 3.8.0 by Datical
>   Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Неподдерживаемая кодовая таблица (добавьте orai18n.jar в маршрут классов): CL8MSWIN1251
>   liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Неподдерживаемая кодовая таблица (добавьте orai18n.jar в маршрут классов): CL8MSWIN1251
>           at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:282) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1060) [liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:209) [liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:132) [liquibase.jar:na]
>   Caused by: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Неподдерживаемая кодовая таблица (добавьте orai18n.jar в маршрут классов): CL8MSWIN1251
>           at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:24) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:280) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           ... 3 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Неподдерживаемая кодовая таблица (добавьте orai18n.jar в маршрут классов): CL8MSWIN1251
>           at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.CatalogSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(CatalogSnapshotGenerator.java:47) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:66) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:69) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:315) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init(DatabaseSnapshot.java:100) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.(DatabaseSnapshot.java:59) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:39) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:217) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:190) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot(DiffCommand.java:221) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createDiffResult(DiffCommand.java:143) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.command.core.GenerateChangeLogCommand.run(GenerateChangeLogCommand.java:46) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:19) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           ... 4 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Неподдерживаемая кодовая таблица (добавьте orai18n.jar в маршрут классов): CL8MSWIN1251
>           at oracle.sql.CharacterSetUnknown.failCharsetUnknown(CharacterSetFactoryThin.java:233) ~[ojdbc8.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
>           at oracle.sql.CharacterSetUnknown.convert(CharacterSetFactoryThin.java:194) ~[ojdbc8.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.throughDbCharset(PhysicalConnection.java:10365) ~[ojdbc8.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.enquoteIdentifier(PhysicalConnection.java:10442) ~[ojdbc8.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.enquoteIdentifier(OracleStatement.java:6452) ~[ojdbc8.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3853) ~[ojdbc8.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:270) ~[ojdbc8.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getString(GeneratedResultSet.java:596) ~[ojdbc8.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.getDatabaseCatalogNames(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:149) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.CatalogSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(CatalogSnapshotGenerator.java:35) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>           ... 18 common frames omitte

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you try `--classpath=ojdbc8.jar;orai18n.jar`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it didn't work

Comment: Are you onj Windows or Linux? On Linux, the classpath separator is `:`

The other option is to just put the driver jar and the `oai18n.jar` in the `<liquibase_home>/lib` directory. All jars in that directory are added the the classpath by the liquibase shell script.

Comment: Also, it may be that the error is coming from the database side rather than the client side. I'd need to see a fuller stack trace to tell whether that was the case though.

Comment: @SteveDonie I use Windows. I put all jar files in the <liquibase_home>/lib, but i also can't run command. I added full stack trace in main question

Comment: I really am not sure how to help here. It appears that your database is set up to use the bulgarian character encoding, `CL8MSWIN1251` and I don't know if Liquibase will even work with that.

Comment: @SteveDonie i fix this problem. I changed NLS LANG in DB server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fix this problem. I changed NLS LANG in DB server.

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
    <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```